# How to query a nullable @OneToOne relationship with JPA

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have `Entity1` and `Entity2`. They have a OneToOne nullable relationship.

```
@Entity
class Entity1 {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "entity2")
   @JoinColumn(nullable = true)    
   private Entity2 entity2;
   ...
}
```

**How can I query all `Entity1` objects that has a null `entity2`?**

Because if I do:

```
SELECT e FROM Entity1 e WHERE e.entity2 IS NULL
```

JPA engine do a JOIN between the two tables and put a useless WHERE clausule (`WHERE entity_id = NULL`). Resuming, it executes an useless native SQL.
How can

**Current solution:**

Reading the OpenJPA documentation, I found that Native Queries should be used to workaround JPA limitations. I can get it very easy using native query and I'm currently doing it, but I would like to avoid to use it.

Comment: Can you give more specific details about how these Entities are associated to each other? Are you using the `@JoinColumn` or `mappedBy` method of linking, or perhaps this is a `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`?

Comment: I added it on the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply run this JPQL query:

```
SELECT e1 
FROM Entity1 e1 
LEFT JOIN e1.entity2 e2
WHERE e2 IS NULL
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is what you were looking for.

Comment: It worked. Have you learned this reading any special documentation? I would like to understand it better.

Comment: It's standard SQL. Any [SQL tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) will probably cover this.

Comment: I wast talking about the JPQL. In SQL I did correctly.

Comment: I don't know if there's a reference doc covering it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done without performing join and using JPA query. Check out the following code snippet:

```java
@Entity
class Entity1 {
   ...
   @OneToOne(...)
   @JoinColumn(name="entity2ID")
   private Entity2 entity2;
   @Column(name="entity2ID", nullable=true, insertable=true, updatable=true)
   private Long entity2ID;
   ...
}
```

Simply map the joining column in entity as insertable/updatable as FALSE. The Make sure that you absolutely not provide setter method for xyz or joining column. Once this is done you can use following query:

```sql
SELECT e FROM Entity1 e WHERE e.entity2ID IS NULL
```

This won't perform any joins as you are querying for joining column directly.

Comment: Good solution, but I think the Vlad answer is easy to maintain.