# Querying a nullable @OneToOne relationship with JPA (inverse way)

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

My case is just the converse of this other question:
[Querying a nullable @OneToOne relationship with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630642/querying-a-nullable-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa)

How can I filter the null values of the non-SQL attribute of a @OneToOne relationship on the mappedBy side. The cited question dealt with the @JoinColumn side.

Comment: How did you map the entities?

Comment: Plain old `@OneToOne(optional = true, mappedBy = "entity2") private Entity1 entity1;` in the part not explicit in the cited example, so your answer was precisely what I was wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e2
FROM Entity1 e1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN e1.entity2 e2
WHERE e1 IS NULL
```